# What was the purpose of the "VTR 1" and "VTR 2" video casettes in Deep Fear?

Tags: deep-fear

There are two video tapes which can be collected in the EU localization of the Sega Saturn game "Deep Fear" and watched in a projection room:

- [VTR 1 (labelled "Cage", a short clip of a wireframe of the "Big Table" underwater base)](https://deepfear.fandom.com/wiki/VTR_1).
- [VTR 2 (labelled "Sexual Body", a short clip of a wireframe of a submarine)](https://deepfear.fandom.com/wiki/VTR_2).

Is it known whether these had any purpose, e.g. whether they had more substantial content in Japanese which was never localized into English, or whether something else can be recorded onto them?  I have not found any details regarding them in the walkthroughs I have clicked through.